# what effect does changing the datatype in a pandas dataframe or series have?

Tags: python, pandas

Specifically,

If I don't *need* to change the datatype, is it better left alone?  Does it copy the whole column of a dataframe? Does it copy the whole dataframe?  Or does it just alter some setting in the dataframe to treat the entries in that column as a particular type?

Also, is there a way to set the type of the columns while the dataframe is getting created?

Here is one example "2014-05-25 12:14:01.929000" is cast as a np.datetime64 when the dataframe is created. then I save the dataframe onto a csv. then I read from the csv, and it becomes an arbitrary object. How would I avoid this? Or how can I re-cast this particular column as an np.datetime64 whilst doing a `pd.DataFrame.read_csv` ....

Thanks.

Comment: If you change the dtype then the series will be copied to the new series using that dtype, to answer your last point use `parse_dates` param in `read_csv`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, I'll check out `parse_dates` and `infer_datetime_format`. Is there a way to set the type of the columns while the dataframe is getting created? And I guess, based on your response, that changing the dtype of a column will not copy the whole dataframe, just the column.  So if I have one line of code for each `astype`, I should be fine.

Comment: DataFrame constructor takes a `dtype` dict like param to allow you to specify the types: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame

Comment: That's cool that you know that. I wish the documentation made that clear. I didn't know it was a dict-type parameter, but I'll play around with it. I'd like to get involved in the pandas project or something similar...